# How to push data from text file into response object in servlet?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a text file with some content  .I should read this text file and put it's content to response object I read content like so  :

```
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\123.txt"));
            String fileContent = br.readLine();
}
```

after his step I don't know How to send this string variable to response object Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in two steps.  The first step, which you have already started to do, is to open the file you want to read.  The second step is to obtain an `OutputStream` from the servlet response and then write to it.  My implementation of `doGet()` below reads your input text file `123.txt` line by line and then writes it to the servlet's `OutputStream`.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=123.txt");

    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();  // get the output stream
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        String currLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\123.txt"));

        // you can change to any encoding you wish; here I have used UTF-8
        while ((currLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            os.write(currLine.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sry I use your code but it didn't work for me.I use Jquery to put this tinput into <div> this is my code  :jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({url: "ServletTest?action=getApplierInfo&nationalCode=123", success: function(result){
$("#div1").html(result);

<div id="div1"></div>  Is it something wrong here?

Comment: You posted a server side problem and now you are asking about a UI problem?

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen I have a submit form I should save user entered information into a text file and after that I should show this information in other web page  .I am very new in web application I'm so confused  .I dont know how to handle this program